# use file comand instead of -name

Tags: bash, file, shell, find

I want to write a shell script that searches in all .txt files the word cat and replaces it with mouse.I wrote the following code:

```
!/bin/bash

read directory

for F in ` find $directory -name '*.txt' -type f`
    do
    echo $F
    `sed -i "s/\<cat\>/mouse/g" $F`
    done
```

I am supposed to use "file" command.I searched for it and it seems like file command finds all the files of a certain type.I want to know how can I include that command in my script.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and explain what it is that you're trying to do with `file`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are in the directory where all *.txt files are. You can execute the following command:

```
find . -name *.txt -exec sed -i "s/\<cat\>/mouse/g" "{}" \;
```